# How do you set the sound device's "profile" at the shell prompt?

Tags: linux, sound-card, alsa, pulse-audio, pipewire

When my displayport monitor goes to sleep, Pipewire forgets the profile for the selected HDMI port audio and falls back to a different HDMI output:

### How it is:

[image: pipewire audio HDMI selection]

### How I want it:

Notice how it says "Digital Sterio (HDMI 3) Output", but I want to set it to HDMI 4 in a shell script:

[image: pipewire audio hdmi4]

### Question

How do I change to the selected HDMI 4 output profile at the command line?

(This is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1800208/1216286), but different.)