# How do you set the default sound device at the shell prompt in pipewire?

Tags: linux, sound-card, alsa, pulse-audio, pipewire

Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1800205/1216286) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/14077/1441797) but with Pipewire *not* pulse audio (unless it is the same, but `pacmd` doesn't work):

**How do you set the default output device (the radio button below) at the command line?**

[image: select audio device]

Comment: Do the last two entries in [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=272777) help with the problem?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @scjorge, no unfortunately not.  I use the GUI for now, but would love to find an cmdline tool  if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `pactl`.
`pactl --help` says:

```
...
pactl [options] set-default-(sink|source) NAME
...
```

and you can get the name examining the output of:
`pactl list sinks`

according to [the arch-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Purism/Librem5Phone) it seems that, with the package `pipewire-pulse`, even though `pulseaudio` is not running or installed, the command `pactl` is usable.

I can confirm this works on one of my debian-based machines (specifically [the Librem5](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Usage) with [mobian](https://mobian.org/)).

As an extra:
`pacmd` will throw an error:

```
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```